# Series labels in Multi-line chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to do a multi-series line chart like the example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

the only difference is i'm trying to do a transition between two sets of data. The transition works absolutely fine but I have no idea how to begin to go about getting the series labels to align with each line as is the case in that example.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to go about it? My code is set up in a slightly different manner than the above example so I'm not able to follow it strictly. But even when I do, the data labels dont come through...

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>    
body {
  font: 10px serif;
}    
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
    fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;

}
    .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 550;
            var height = 600;
            var padding=60;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([padding, width-padding]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height-padding, padding]);        

var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height)


//load CSV
d3.csv("diverge-nonscaled1950.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.India=+d.India;
    d.China=+d.China;
      });


  //compute column names
var seriesNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "date"; })
      .sort();

 //this is dataset one: data is scaled to column name INdia
      var series = seriesNames.map(function(series) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: d.date, y: ((+d[series]/d.India)*100)};
    });

  });

 //this is dataset two: data is scaled to column name China
      var series1 = seriesNames.map(function(series1) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {x: d.date, y: ((+d[series1]/d.China)*100)};
    });

  });


var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
   // .defined(function(d) { return d.country>0; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });   


//domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
 y.domain([0,2300]);
 z.domain(seriesNames)


//axes
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-padding) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("x",0-(height/2.5))
      .attr("y", -50)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("font-size",11)
      .text("Relative per Capita Incomes");;

//draw path
svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(series)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke",function(d, i) { return z(i); })

 //first transition from dataset one to two   
d3.select("svg")
               .on("click",file1);

function file1(){
svg.selectAll(".line").data(series1)
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke",function(d, i) { return z(i); })

d3.select("svg")
               .on("click",file2);

  }

 //second transition back to one
function file2(){
svg.selectAll(".line").data(series)
    .transition().duration(750)
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke",function(d, i) { return z(i); })

d3.select("svg")
               .on("click",file1);


} 



});

</script>
</body>
```

Thanks very much for any help whatsoever...
Avin

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with this a while ago as well. As in the example you posted, you have to use d3's [selection.datum()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum) method, which snags data for individual elements. You will then select the final data point in each series using `thing[thing.length - 1]` and use the x and y values of that point to perform a transform/translate on your text. The relevant part of the code is:

```
 city.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
  })
```

Then the animation is just a matter of updating the transformation, with something like:

```
city.selectAll('text').transition()
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; 
    })
```

You can also view [a chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nsonnad/4175202) I made a while ago that seems to be similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks very much. your chart is definitely similar to what I'm trying to do. hopefully I can adapt it...